# Estimation of Default Probability from Bond

Tags: credit-risk, default-probability

Typically the formula to calculate the `default probability` from `corporate Bond` looks like

$\frac{S}{1-R}$

where $S$ is the spread of `Corporate bond yield` over the `RFR` and $R$ is recovery rate.

I failed to understand the intuition behind this formula. Why this formula refers to the `default probability`?

This might be very trivial, but I really appreciate for any insight on the reasoning.

Comment: This may help http://www.kamakuraco.com/Blog/tabid/231/EntryId/700/Credit-Spreads-and-Default-Probabilities-A-Simple-Model-Validation-Example.aspx

Comment: pls also see here: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/30231/interest-rate-implied-probability-of-default